# How in the world to I use the Developer console with numbers in my name? (Roblox)

Tags: lua

When I try to change my WalkSpeed, for example, it gives me a error. `game.Players.0_0ohiamRDJpower.Character.Humanoid.MaxHealth` = 200
console:1: Incomplete statement: expected assignment or function call
h e l p

Comment: `game.Players["0_0ohiamRDJpower"].Character`

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the dev console, it's this:
game.Workspace.namehere.Humanoid.MaxHealth =
or
game.Workspace.namehere.Humanoid.Health =

Comment: Provide more details with examples code